# Use jQuery to wrap a div around a group of td's

Tags: jquery, html-table

Here is the example code I am working on:

```
<td class="one">content</td>
<td class="two">content</td>
<td class="three">content</td>
<td class="four">content</td>
<td class="five">content</td>
```

I am able to wrap a div around the first td using:

```
$('td.one').wrap('<div class="td-one">');
```

However, I now need to wrap the remaining four td's in a single div...so the desired outcome is:

```
<div class="td-one">
    <td class="one">content</td>
</div>
<div class="td-two-five">
    <td class="two">content</td>
    <td class="three">content</td>
    <td class="four">content</td>
    <td class="five">content</td>
</div>
```

How would I do this with jQuery?

Comment: A `div` is not a valid child of a `table` unless it's contained within a `td` or `th` element.

Comment: Why? What is it you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: The `<colgroup>` tag is probably much more appropriate for this purpose.

Answer (score 7):

The convention is to mark each cell with a class which will act as a wrapper given the convenience of jQuery selectors.

```
<td class="td-one one">content</td>
<td class="td-two-five two">content</td>
<td class="td-two-five three">content</td>
<td class="td-two-five four">content</td>
<td class="td-two-five five">content</td>
```

Then as needed you can work with groups of cells.

```
$(".td-two-five").hide();
```

Comment: +1 for a valid solution, ya whiny baby. `:P` (That was a while back, btw.) This is actually probably all that's needed, but unless the OP gives more information, we won't know.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - I figured someone else would cover the actual `wrap` concept so I went a bit beyond and made some assumptions about what the OP is trying to accomplish.

Comment: All three answers are perhaps equivalent in that one gives the literal (unbiased) answer, one gives a (biased but literal) answer, and the other (yours) gives an appropriate yet completely different approach that's perhaps the best in many cases.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming, for the sake of valid HTML, that you're using `div` elements instead of `td` elements, I'd suggest:

```
<div class="one">content</div>
<div class="two">content</div>
<div class="three">content</div>
<div class="four">content</div>
<div class="five">content</div>

$('div.one').wrap('<div class="cell-one" />').parent('div').siblings().wrapAll('<div class="cell-two-five" />')​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wtUp2/).

Comment: @undefined - My answer isn't valid? :(

Comment: @DavidThomas Because I had wrapped the TDs with a div tag, and you have provided an alternative. although they are not TD tags.

Comment: @undefined, sorry, it was a just a turn of phrase; possibly the comma screwed up the meaning? Think *exclamatory*, rather than *quizzical* =D